# Can't pass data to serviceWorker once it's registered as it's null

Tags: javascript, service-worker

I'm new with serviceWorker and trying to pass data to it after it's registered a way like

```
navigator.serviceWorker.register('/serviceWorker.js').then(function () {
    navigator.serviceWorker.controller.postMessage({'hello': 'world'});
});
```

But I receive the error

> Cannot read properties of null (reading 'postMessage')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wait until service worker is ready and then post a message

like this :

```
if (navigator.serviceWorker) {

  navigator.serviceWorker.register('service-worker.js');

  navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then( registration => {
    registration.active.postMessage({'hello': 'world'});
  });

}
```

or if you want to use controller you can do it in this way :

```
navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(function(serviceWorkerRegistration) {
  // Let's see if you have a subscription already
  return serviceWorkerRegistration.pushManager.getSubscription();
})
.then(function(subscription) {
  if (!subscription) {
    return;
  }
  navigator.serviceWorker.controller.postMessage({'hello': 'world'});

})
```